# Can a RAID 0 disk/config be rebuilt?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid-0

Recently one of the hard drives of one of my RAID 0 configuration gave an error.

What do I do now I'm hoping that I can replace that faulty disk with a new hard drive and that the RAID can rebuild itself. (using Intel Matrix Storage Console) Is this possible? Though I doubt it. Is there anyway that I can rebuild the RAID? or have I lost all the matter on it.

*TECH INFO: I have a software raid on an Intel DG965WH motherboard and the current operating system is Windows*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, RAID 0 does not incorporate any fault tolerance.  Your data is now corrupt.

However, if the failed drive is able to somewhat work, you may be able to duplicate its contents onto another drive and reassemble the RAID yourself, or a data recovery firm may be able to recover your files--the latter option will cost you either hundreds or thousands of dollars.

If you want to try the recovery yourself, your replacement drive will need to be at least as big as your bad drive.  Put the bad drive and your new drive in a different computer (so you won't mess up your RAID configuration), boot from an Ubuntu Linux Live CD, then type these commands:

```
sudo bash
fdisk -l
```

After the second command, make note of which drive is /dev/sda and which is /dev/sdb.

Assuming /dev/sda is the bad drive and /dev/sdb is the new, good drive, run these commands:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1m
```

If this fails, try [dd_rescue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dd_rescue.1.html).

Once the drive is fully duplicated, reconnect the new drive into your other computer exactly how the bad drive was connected--if you're lucky, it will boot up as if the RAID never failed, but some of your files will most likely be corrupt.

Comment: will try this definitely, can't I use Acronis True Image to do the same?

Comment: You can try TrueImage, but I think it requires you to have an intact filesystem--I guess I've always gone straight to dd when I knew I needed a block-level copy.